# Does halo 4 Spartan ops require Internet to use?

Tags: xbox-360, halo-4

So I have an Xbox live silver membership (the basic one) and I wanted to know if it is at all possible to play without an Internet connection. My bandwidth is limited to a slow speed right now (not sure how fast). I want to know how I can use it and if I can use it. I intend on doing this offline

Some more info

I do have the second disk, but currently uninstalled because I need more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need internet or an Xbox Live Gold membership to play. However, you will only be able to play the singleplayer Campaign mode (and other singleplayer modes), not the online arenas or PVP. Sorry, hope that helps though.

Answer (score 3):

In Halo 4 from the Xbox 360, yes, it requires internet connection and an Xbox Live Gold Membership to play. If you were to play it from the Halo Chief Master Collection, it does not<sup>[[1]](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Spartan_Ops)</sup>

Comment: You had a great answer too, but I can only do one!